# Return ajax response as html to Backbone View from custom function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to render a partial view within a Backbone View with it's render method. I created a sort of helper to do this.

```
var DashboardPartial = (function(){

    var _getPartialView = function() {

        $.ajax({
          url: _baseUrl + _url,
        })

        .done(function(response) {
          _returnView(response);
        })
        .fail(function() {
          console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
          console.log("complete");
        });

    };

    var _returnView = function (response) {
       return response;
    };

    return  {
      get: function (url) {
        _url = url;
        _baseUrl = '/dashboard/';
        _getPartialView();
      },

    };

}());
```

So, what I want to do is call DashboardPartial.get('url') and use the response within the Backbones View render method. Something like the following:

```
render: function() {
    partial = DashboardPartial.get('url');
    this.$el.html(partial); 
    return this;
}
```

The problem is that the function does get the partial from the server, but I can't find a way to return the response. Doing console.log(response) inside the DashboardPartial function does show the partial, but I want to be able to return it and then pass it as a variable to "this.$el.html()".

Answer (score 0):

You should return deferred ($.ajax returns it by default) from helper:

```
var DashboardPartial = (function(){

    var _getPartialView = function() {
        return $.ajax({
          url: _baseUrl + _url,
        });
    };

    return  {
       get: function (url) {
         _url = url;
         _baseUrl = '/dashboard/';
         return _getPartialView();
       },
    };
}());
```

And then use it in your render:

```
render: function() {
    var self = this,
        dfd = $.Deferred();

    DashboardPartial.get('url').done(function(partial){
        self.$el.html(partial);
        dfd.resolve();
    });

    return dfd; // use this outside, to know when view is rendered; view.render().done(function() { /* do stuff with rendered view */});
}
```

However, you could use requirejs for this, plus requirejs-text plugin to load templates, because your view has dependency on partial.

As I understood, you want render different partials using one backbone view.

You could create factory, smth like this:

```
var typeToTemplateMap = {};

typeToTemplateMap["backboneViewWithFirstPartial"] = firstPartial;

function(type) {
   return typeToTemplateMap[type];
}
```

And then use it in your view:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.partial = partialFactory(options.type);
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.partial);
    return this;
}
```

This is how it would look like using requirejs:

```
// factory.js

define(function(require) {

    var partialOne = require("text!path/to/partialOne.htm"), // it's just html files
        partialTwo = require("text!path/to/partialTwo.htm");

   var typeToPartialMap = {};

   typeToPartialMap["viewWithFirstPartial"] = partialOne;
   typeToPartialMap["viewWithSecondartial"] = partialTwo;

   return function(type) {
       return typeToPartialMap[type];
   }
});

// view.js

define(function(require){

   var Backbone = require("backbone"), // this paths are configured via requirejs.config file.
       partialFactory = require("path/to/factory");

   return Backbone.View.extend({

       initialize: function(options) {
           this.partial = partialFactory(options.type);
       },

       render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.partial);
            return this;
       }
   });

});

// Another_module.js, could be another backbone view.
define(function(require) {
   var MyView = require("path/to/MyView"),
       $ = require("jquery");

   var myView = new MyView({type: "firstPartial"});

   myView.render(); // or render to body $("body").append(myView.render().$el);
});
```

You should consider using requirejs, because you doing almost the same, but without dependencies handling.

Docs on requirejs can be found here: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Comment: Thanks four your answer, but I have another question though. Why this: dfd = $.Deferred() ?

Comment: You can't return "this" from render function because DashboardPartial.get('url') is async. You don't actually know when partial is fetched from the server, so if you will return "this" from render function, at that moment partial may not be appended to $el.

So you should create deferred object. https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/. It means you wait till partial will be fetched and appended to $el. And then you can use your rendered view. view.render().done(function(){ do stuff with your rendered view }); Requirejs handles this problem, by loading all the dependencies before.